# Local real-time lightning tracker site?

Tags: lightning, atmospheric-science, meteorology

Is there a site that tracks lightning strikes at a local level in real-time?

Google results for "lightning tracker" yield several sites, but none do this.

It seems easy enough to set up. Have volunteers report:

- their location
- the time they saw the strike
- the direction of the strike, to the nearest 45 degree (eg, 
  "southwest" or "east")
- the delay between the lightning and the thunder (ie, the distance 
  in fifths of a mile)
- optional: description of the lightning strike

Of course, portions of the report could be automated (eg, geolocated tweets).

It would then be easy to map lightning strikes at a given time, watch 
a storm move, etc, down to the several-hundred-feet level.

Since this seems easy to do, I'm sure someone has done it, no?

Comment: Why not just use an existing [automated system](http://www.weather.com/maps/activity/golf/uslightningstrikes_large.html) instead of relying on highly fallible humans? Not sure there's global coverage with such systems, but there seems to be at least an entire continent covered...

Comment: Can you zoom to a local level on this map? (doesn't seem possible). And it hasn't been updated in 15 minutes? I'm talking about something minute-to-minute here.

Comment: But to answer your question - no, nobody has done this kind of thing. Why? Because ob the obvious reasons @Kyle stated: Why should you deploy a lot of volunteers, when the automated system has good accuracy (the Siemens system deployed in Germany claims to have a precision of 200 m) and few seconds reaction time (also, their statement). Just to clarify - these precision specs cost money, of course - and it seems to be the "ask us when you're interested" kind of money ;)

Comment: It's a good question. Aircraft can carry [*storm-scopes*](http://www.as.l-3com.com/products/stormscope/), and possibly there is such a thing at local weather broadcasters. Also [*look here*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_detection).

Comment: this satellite map for strikes during the last hour has even a color scale http://www.intellicast.com/Storm/Severe/Lightning.aspx

Comment: and here is a site for Europe http://en.allmetsat.com/images/lightning-europe.php

Comment: @Kyle (and anna-v), unless I'm missing something, aren't those maps scaled to about 6 miles per pixel? I'm looking for a city-level solution, where I can pinpoint lightning strikes in near-real-time down to the several-hundred-feet level. Am I missing something in those maps? They don't appear to be zoomable.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I googled "google maps lightning" (sort of obvious in retrospect), and found:

http://www.blitzortung.org/Webpages/index.php?lang=en&page=1&subpage_0=10

which is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. It appears that:

http://www.fs.fed.us/fire/planning/nist/alms.htm

may do this also, but I hate Windows too much to see if it works (any volunteers)? It's 2007 date suggests it may no longer be working.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is access to the [National Lightning Detection Network](http://www.vaisala.com/en/products/thunderstormandlightningdetectionsystems/Pages/NLDN.aspx).  As far as I know, the service is not free.  There are also multiple other for-fee access to lightning data.  I believe [Accuweather](http://accuweather.com) offers this as does [Allison House](https://www.allisonhouse.com/).  The Allison House data will integrate into [Radar Scope](http://radarscope.tv/products/) and [GRLevelX](http://www.grlevelx.com/) to display lightning data with level 2/3 radar and other meteorological information.